# How do I fix my Ruby installation

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, osx-snow-leopard

I rather cleverly (or not in hindsight) installed RVM, which kept hanging whilst compiling Rubies.

I have removed the .rvm directory but now my system has reverted to Ruby 1.8.7 i.e. when I type:

```
ruby -v
which ruby
```

they both point to 1.8.7.

How do I get the ruby command to point to my 1.9.1 installation, which is located in /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1?  I'm on OSX 10.6.

Thanks

Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `/usr/local/lib` (why isn't it bin?) in your PATH and *before* `/usr/lib` in this case?

What is `which ruby` returning?

EDIT: My de-facto /usr/local link for OS X (and in general) is on [Hivelogic](http://hivelogic.com/articles/using_usr_local)

Comment: Not sure why it is lib and not bin. My .bash_login file has the following:

export PATH="/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

I added /usr/local/lib after your comment. Do I need to restart to have the above changes take effect?

Comment: Ignore the above. Quit the terminal and it's all working now! Thanks

Comment: As a future note, if you make changes to your .bash_login file, it won't be applied to your current session, so you will either have to start a new session or you can do `source .bash_login`.

Answer (score 0):

After a botched update of ruby gems, I used Time Machine to restore the folders in `/Library/Ruby` and that worked fine.